# MySQL Error Code 1265 : Data Truncated for column

Tags: mysql

Running into Error Code: 1265 with the following code and data.
Data was exported as CSV.
The score column containing float data appears is source of issue as without this column the data loading works.
I have tried using Decimals and this works but I curious why floats do not work yet i'm working small figures.

```
CREATE TABLE dummy(
    entry_id INT NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    score FLOAT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (entry_id)
);

LOAD DATA INFILE "C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/test_data.csv"
INTO TABLE dummy
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

**Below is the sample csv file:**

entry_id,first_name,last_name,score

1,Joshua,Mbweka,3.56

2,Mary,Njoroge,25.23

3,Adam,Kimanzi,64.41

4,Eve,Faluna,56.13

5,Lester,Chuma,89.21

Comment: please show a sample of your csv

Comment: *see above the link to csv file* Wrong picture. CSV file is text file, not worksheet. Post 3-4 lines from it into the question text (not as a picture).

Comment: *`OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"'`* Imagine the impoorting process finds dquote char... how it can distinguish what is it - enclosing or escaping?

Comment: @Babypowder please as text

Comment: @Akina  thanks for suggestion - done shared as text below the SQL code

Comment: 1) None value is enclosed with dquote - so `ENCLOSED` not needed. 2) I predict that the file is Windows-style text, if so then you must use `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'` (in current state `\n` is treated as a symbol in a value which causes truncation).

Comment: @Akina this worked,  thank you very much.